# How does this (phishing) website has an identical domain with the authentic one?

Tags: domains, search-engine-indexing, unicode, phishing

I google `webgraphviz.com` and the first two results are:

[image]

How does the first one, which redirects to a pharmacy website, have the identical domain with the second one? I even suspect this is a kind of faking domain in which the attacker uses similar characters (e.g. Α (capital Greek `α`) and A (capital English `a`), but checking with the fake one by copying the domain and paste it to the [Non-ASCII checker](https://pages.cs.wisc.edu/%7Emarkm/ascii.html) I find it only contains ASCII characters. So how is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I expect the site was hacked and cleaned up, and Google (for now) remembers both.

When I go to both the first and second link it takes me to the identical looking page.

Comment: How can Google not recognize both have the same domain? The second result takes me to the real site

Comment: I just tried it again and it appears there is now only one answer returned by Google.  I expect that the answer is "eventual consistency" - ie Googles data being inconsistent for a while, with different crawlers advising different information due to spidering at different times - and then both being aggregated.

Comment: But even so, how can one same domain take me to different website? Anyway, I still see different results on my side